# Operation not permitted

Tags: android

adb shell "run-as package.name chmod 666 /data/data/package.name/databases/file"
データベースファイルをPC上にpullしたくて、上記のコマンドを打ち込むと下記のエラーが返ってきます。

「run-as: exec failed for chmod Error:Operation not permitted」

原因を色々と調べていたところ、root権限を取得しなければいけないらしく、adb shellと打ち、suとコマンドを打ち込んでも、「su: not found」とエラーが出てきてrootが取得できず、どうすればいいか分かりません。
adb shell "run-as・・・・・・を正常に実行できるようにするにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
すみませんが宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `run-as`コマンドはそもそもデバッガがアタッチされたアプリ（つまり自作したもの）にしか使えないのですが、そこは問題ないですか？Androidのバージョンによってはroot権限がなくても（`run-as`の権限で）`cd`コマンドで一度`/sdcard/`にコピーした上で`adb pull`することができるらしいですが、自分の端末だと権限が足りませんでした。DBの内容をPCで確認したいだでけあれば、単純にSDカードに書き出す処理を作った方が早いと思います。

Comment: すみません、返信を忘れていました。すみません。手詰まりなのでSDカードに書き出す処理を作りたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お使いの端末がわかりませんが、Root権限を取れない端末なのではないでしょうか。

特に日本で販売されている端末などではRoot権限を取れないようになっている端末が多いです。
そういった端末でもシェルで入ることはできますが、suなどができないので一部のファイルへのアクセスなどができないといった形になります。

**追記**

MOTOROLA RAZR M 201Mとのことですが、Root化の情報が検索すると色々と出てくるのでRoot化を行っていないのであれば、Root権限が必要な操作はできないです。

- http://blog.goo.ne.jp/thomas_riker/e/4ed47e1cadd69188b991b367f5cd0971

Root化についてはメーカーからの保証が受けられなくなどの相応のリスクがあるので注意してください。
またRoot化してファイルを引き出したとしても、そのファイルが何らかのプロテクトなどをアプリ側でかけている可能性もあります。
そもそもどういったことをしたかったのかわかりませんが、望み薄な気がします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
現在使用している端末は「MOTOROLA RAZR™ M 201M」です。
そうなのですか。端末のファイルへアクセスしたかったのですが仕方がないのですね...。

Comment: 了解しました。他の方法で試してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。